# SQL Server table design with non fixed column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need your help in designing one table.

I have some groups tables and we need to load data in that group tables from xml files that contain column names and data.

The column name is actually index of some main column like `activity_col1`, `activity_col2` and so on and not fixed every time, there is possibility that same table file contains 1000 columns sometimes and 10 column values some time also there is maximum limit is also defined so no file will contain more than 
2000 column per group.

So I need to design a table that is the best possible solution for this also I need to do the aggregation of column values. The files contain min level data and I need to store this data in min table and after that this min data need to be aggregated in an hour, day, week and month.

If I create max columns in all tables but data will not come every time in all columns so this design seems not good because most of the values will be null.

If I insert column name as rows in column_name column and values against each column value in values column then aggregation will be a tedious task for me 
and it will impact performance.

Please suggest.

Comment: I don't fully understand how many types of data are there in the xml files. Is this for one big list or several lists of different things? Do you need the minimum per row? Or maximum of each column per some period of time? Do you have several rows per hour? You say "max columns in all tables", but I thought you are only talking about one table.
You can also try to get help in https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: In SQL Server you can store xml data as `nvarchar(max)` and use xquery over them - [SQL Server XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server) ;).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but it's more complicated to build, to query and to insert, and readability is very low.

You require a schema-less design, Allowing an unlimited number of columns,
your best bet is probably to use a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) solution. Even though the weaknesses of `EAV` relative to relational databases also apply to `NoSQL` alternatives.

Also take a look at here :

[Benefits of NoSQL](https://www.devbridge.com/articles/benefits-of-nosql/)

**Recommendations** (as priority):

1. Choice `EAV`, If you are using a relational-database and this is
   where you turn either the whole table or a portion (in another
   table) on its side. This is a good choice if you already have a
   relational-database in-house that you can't move away from easily.
2. Choice `NoSQL`, If does not matter kind of `DBMS` for you It is very
   flexible and fast and not all of the report writers out there
   support this style of storage. There are many example database
   implementations of `NoSQL`. The one that seems to be most popular
   right now, is `MongoDB`.

and the last option that **I don't recommend you to use it**:

3. Choice Standard tables with `XML` columns, If the you don't need to
   query them, and you just want to be stored and retrieved as plain
   text for using some extra usage.

I hope to be helpful for you:)

Comment: i need this to be design in microsoft sql server using sql queries only.

Comment: So choice first option. It is better choice than `SQL Server XML`. The `XML` datatype is far less accessible than regular tables and fields when it comes to data processing and reporting.